# MySQL DB tables not being read, can't delete DB

Tags: mysql, sql, xampp

I had a running MySQL server on my mac with XAMPP, however my computer unexpectedly shut down, and when I restarted it and accessed my DB, it gave me the error:
`db.table does not exist`
When I investigated further, I realized that the .ibd file still exist, and therefore I extracted them. Then, I tried to remove the database to re-add the .ibd files. However, it fails. How can I restore my tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have still the create statements for your table or can you recreate them?
Then you can [Recover an InnoDB table from only an .ibd file](http://www.chriscalender.com/?p=28)

Comment: Don't have create statements, only ibd files.

Comment: then try to write them anew